# Why same query results are different on BigQuery editor and sqlalchemy?

Tags: google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

My bigquery query is :

```
SELECT d.type AS `error_type`, count('d.type') AS `count` 
FROM `table_android`, unnest(`table_android`.`exceptions`) AS `d` 
WHERE `table_android`.`event_timestamp` BETWEEN '2022-12-15' AND '2022-12-20' GROUP BY `error_type` ORDER BY `count` desc;
```

This query is working fine in bigquery editor. But same version of query with sqlalchemy I could not get same results.

sqlalchemy query :

```
sa.select(
    sa.literal_column("d.type").label("Error_Type"),
    sa.func.count("Error_Type").label("count"),
)
.select_from(sa.func.unnest(table_android.c.exceptions).alias("d"))
.group_by("Error_Type")
.order_by(desc("count"))
.where(table_android.c.event_timestamp.between('2022-12-15', '2022-12-20'))
.cte("main_table")
```

Correct result :
[image: Correct result]

Wrong result:
[image: Wrong result]

I am using python-bigquery-sqlalchemy library. table_android.exceptions column struct is like that : [image]
column types :
[image]

And this is render of sqlalchemy query :

`` SELECT `d`.`type` AS `Error_Type`, count(`d`.`type`) AS `count`  FROM `table_android`, unnest(`table_android`.`exceptions`) AS `d`  WHERE `table_android`.`event_timestamp` BETWEEN '2022-12-05' AND '2022-12-20' GROUP BY `Error_Type` ORDER BY `count` DESC ``

I see correct result in bigquery editor. But sqlalchemy is not shows correct result. How should i edit my sqlalchemy query for correct results ?

Comment: You original query is confusing, is this supposed to be a cartesian product / cross join between these selectables: ``` FROM `table_android`, unnest(`table_android`.`exceptions`) AS `d` ```?  The `sqlalchemy` version doesn't seem to do that but I don't understand how it would work reliably in the original query.

Comment: @IanWilson thanks for comment. Because I should get some values from nested records. `table_android.c.exceptions` column is an array of struct. And  i am using unnest function because of this is the only way that can getting some data from nested records column.  Do you have a recommendation ?

Comment: Can you post table schema and driver you are using?

Comment: Sure, I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have bigquery so I can't test this but I think you want [`column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) and not `literal_column`.  Also I think you can create an implicit `CROSS JOIN` by including both the table and the unnested column in the `select_from`.

```py
# I'm testing with postgresql but it doesn't have easy to make structs
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

table_android = Table("table_android", metadata,
                      Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                      Column("exceptions", postgresql.ARRAY(String)),
                      Column("event_timestamp", Date))

from sqlalchemy.sql import column, func, select

d = func.unnest(table_android.c.exceptions).alias("d")
# You might be able to do d.column["type"].label("Error_Type")
type_col = column("d.type").label("Error_Type")
count_col = func.count(type_col).label("count")

print (select(
    type_col,
    count_col,
)
.select_from(table_android, d)
.group_by(type_col)
.order_by(count_col)
.where(table_android.c.event_timestamp.between('2022-12-15', '2022-12-20'))
.cte("main_table"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  also this query getting wrong result. Maybe this is a problem about sqlalchemy and bigquery incompatiblity?

Comment: @BurakÇayır Can you include the SQL that is output when you run the query with sqlalchemy?  Ie. either print it before calling execute/all or turn `echo=True` on the engine.

Comment: Well I'm stumped.  Do you think there could some obscure client setting affecting how you are connecting?  There seems to be a lot of client connection settings as well as specifying the `location` of the dataset.  I'm grasping at straws here though.

Comment: I think this is not a problem about connection setting. Because that was the only query that returns wrong result.